# How do I determine all the system and library calls made by an EXE

Tags: c, linux, windows, reverse-engineering, wine

I'm looking into why Warframe does not work on WINE in Linux, and I suspect that it is due to missing system or library calls.  I'd like to determine what calls it makes, and compare them to calls supported directly or indirectly by WINE.

Comment: Isn't wine reporting the unsupported calls?

Comment: Kind of.  It reports some runtime failures.  It is very hard for me to parse through the output, it also reports things which may not be problem.  It may also be a call not implemented in the same way.  But knowing the calls made can limit what I need to go through, and if I then remove calls that are known to be good it leaves many fewer code paths which need to be looked at.

Comment: It also would allow for planning and prioritizing paths instead of fixing a few errors at one given time.  It's primarily for debugging a complex system, so the more clear it can be made, the better.

Comment: For a complete log of every single API call a program makes, run it with `WINEDEBUG=+relay`. You'll get several gigabytes of output that should somewhere contain what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called [EXE Import Viewer](http://www.heaventools.com/PE_Explorer_exe-import-viewer.htm) it doesn't continuously list the function calls but it does reveal the dependencies of the the exe.

From the site:

> EXE Import Viewer shows the information about linked libraries and functions, the list of function that an executable file imports, and the DLL's from which the program imports these functions.

This might be a good place to start for your problem.

Comment: Another tool for that is the good old [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which shows per-dll calls and allows you to drill down to what the program DLLs themselves use.